# How to remove auto generated comments in NetBeans? (// NOI18N)

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have an application written in Java Swing and I am using NetBeans 7.2.1. In the generated code there is a lot of auto generated comments //NOI18N.

Unfortunately, I can't find in the templates where this guy is defined.

Does anybody know how I can remove this comment from the generated code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This control mechanism is part of the internationalization of NetbeansIDE**, not a given from any template.

You can customize these automatics comments following these steps:

- View Properties Form:

[image: View Properties Form]

- Deselect Automatic Internationalization

[image: Deselect Automatic Internationalization]

- Reload Form

[image: Reload Form]

*You can also get much more information by opening the inside netbeans help and searching the key word "Automatically Internationalizing"*